# Concepts: require class method return type is nested type of same class

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to implement the following concept

```
template<typename T>
concept GameLogic = requires(T a)  {
    typename T::StateType;
    typename T::EventType;
    { a.initialState()->T::StateType }; // <-- relevant bit
};
```

where I want to impose that `initialState()` return type is a nested type of the same class.

The concept definition doesn't raise errors (gcc 9.2), but the following implementation of `GameLogic` fails to satisfy the requirement:

```
class SimpleGameLogic {
public:

    using StateType = SimpleState;
    using EventType = SimpleEvent;

    StateType initialState() {
        return _initialState;
    }

private:
    StateType _initialState;

};
```

I have tried some variations of the above syntax but cannot find the right one... or this may not be implemented yet? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three issues:

```
{ a.initialState()->T::StateType }; // <-- relevant bit
```

First, the syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
{ a.initialState() } -> T::StateType;
```

Second, you're missing `typename`:

```
{ a.initialState() } -> typename T::StateType;
```

Third, in C++20, we don't have `-> Type` anymore (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61412758/2069064)). The thing on the right-hand side of the arrow has to be a constraint. Something like:

```
{ a.initialState() } -> std::same_as<typename T::StateType>;
```

And once you fix that, [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/0wJhxu).

Comment: The weird part about this: `a.initialState()->T::StateType` can actually be a valid expression, so the compiler can't diagnose it...

Comment: @T.C.: It couldn’t be at the same time as `typename T::StateType` being satisfied, so it should merit a warning (someday).

Comment: @DavisHerring Don't we look up `T` in the class of the object expression first? So it can mean something that's not the template paramter?

Comment: @T.C.: That’s the subject of [CWG1089](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1089); the thought is that a strict reading would make it ambiguous, but I think it should reliably find the template parameter (though not via the mechanism suggested in the issue).

Comment: @DavisHerring aha, so after [CWG1111](https://wg21.link/CWG1111) we unambiguously find a member `T` if it exists, but P1787 will reverse it.

Comment: @T.C.: Something like that, but it’s complicated by the fact that we can’t look up `T` in the class scope right away because it’s a dependent type.  P1787 isn’t supposed to change the CWG1111 case.

Comment: Good lord you folks know your stuff.